# Why work is done on the system in this case?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Consider the following situation:

> The system is the air contained within a bicycle tire along with a
>   tire pump connected to it. The pump plunger is pushed down, forcing air into the tire. Assume this interaction is over before the air cools significantly.

In the book where this is being discussed, it is said that work is done on the system.

I can't get the idea here. As far as I know, we have two extensive variables: the volume $V$ and the number of moles $N$ of gas molecules which make up the air inside the tire.

So, we could write the internal energy as $U=U(S,V,N)$, and thus we would have:

$$dU = TdS - PdV + \mu dN$$

Now we see the following: if one forces air into the tire, two things happen in my point of view:

1. The number of molecules of gas making up the air in the tire will increase. Since we are forcing more air inside, we are effectively changing the number of moles $N$. In that case, since $dN$ is positive, we have chemical work $dW_{\mathrm{chemical}}=\mu dN$ being done on the system.
2. On the other hand, the volume will also increase. Trying to imagine the situation, as air gets injected into the system, the volume will expand, "pushing the tire out". If we picture a flat tire and imagine air being injected into it, we see that as the tire is filled with air, its volume increases. In that case, it seems to me that we are also pushing the boundaries of the system by the expanding the volume. So we would have a positive $dV$, and consequently, we have mechanical work $dW_{\mathrm{mechanical}}=-PdV$. This is work done *by the system* as it expands.

The book doesn't talk about chemical or mechanical work. It just says "work is done on the system". But from my point of view, chemical work is done on the system while the system does mechanical work on its surroundings.

Is my point of view correct? Or am I completely wrong? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that the indicate that the system is the tire *and the pump*, so $dN=0$, because the system of the pump and tire is closed, so the volume of the system, in fact *decreases* because of the motion of the piston, so $\delta W_{\text{mechanical}} = -P dV$ is *positive*, since $dV$ is negative, so that is how the "Work done on the system" results.

It's also notable here that they specify only *one* compression, so that the system will remain closed, if the piston refilled with outside air, the analysis may be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

The convention of most thermodynamic books is such that the signs of work and heat indicate the energy *added* to the system. So, *PdV* (without *minus* sign)  is the energy *done by* the system. The reason the book calls it energy *done on* the system is that it includes the *minus* sign. I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

> Now we see the following: if one forces air into the tire two things happen in my point of view:
>
> The number of molecules of gas making up the air will increase. Since we are forcing more air inside the tire, we are effectively changing the number of moles NN. In that case, since dN is positive, we have one chemical work dWchemical=μdN  being done on the system.
>
> On the other hand, the volume will also increase. Trying to imagine the situation, as air gets injected into the system, the volume will expand, "pushing the tire out". If we picture one flat tire and imagine air being inject into it, we see that as the tire is filled with air, its volume increase. In that case it seems to me that we are also pushing the boundaries of the system by the expanding the volume. So we would have a positive dV and consequently we have mechanical work dWmechanical=−PdV. This is work done by the system as it expands.
>
> The book doesn't talk about chemical or mechanical work. It just says "work is done on the system". But from my point of view, chemical work is done on the system while the system does mechanical work on its surroundings.
>
> Is my point of view correct? Or am I completely wrong? Am I missing something here?

Please consider an alternative view:

Here we do not talk about chemical process or negative work done by the system as one is doing positive mechanical work through the piston of the pump in compressing the air adiabatically and pushing it in the tire.

1. when one is pressing the bicycle pump giving a number of strokes say N ,he is compressing the gas and as the valve opens to send the gas in tire -

The event can be broken up in parts to assess the total amount of work done .Suppose in i th stroke a pressure Pi is developed .

The process is quick so an adiabatic process can be assumed and using adiabatic  ideal gas relationship the change in Temperature of the air can be calculated as a function of new temperature say T'.

Work done in this process can be equated to
 W'=no. of molesx sp. heat at constant volume x change in temperature.

2. This hot gas is pushed in the tire so work done  W''  in pushing it in terms of pressure
   inside the tire developed and new volume can be expressed.
3. The sum of above two work is the total work done W = W' +w''
4. the change in internal energy of the air in the tire can be related to total work done on air pushed in.
5. Finally the total work done can easily be expressed as function of new pressure developed and the new volume.

and a model estimate can be made with real values of Pressure developed ,temp. change and number of strokes.

A model calculation gives that to pump up a tire in say 10 minutes 
giving 200 strokes with max. temp. of 192 degree Celsius  and

pressure max. of 4.65 atmosphere one needs about 115 watts of power delivered through the pump.

Please refer to the following for details of the above calculation:

> http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/tirepump.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you make the following statement

"The system is the air contained within a bicycle tire along with a tire pump connected to it"

then you have defined your system and in one stroke the number of molecules of gas in the system is constant.
Since the change is rapid you assume that it is an adiabatic change and so you do not have to worry about heat.

The work done on the system is done by an external force compressing the gas in the pump.
The work done by the system is the work done increasing the volume of the tyre against atmospheric pressure.

The net work done on the system is the difference between these two quantities and the book says this is positive which is not unreasonable as otherwise this system would be a source of energy and the gas in the system would get colder?